daterangepicker Only Year And Month
I use a daterangepicker and want to display only the year and month and look up the start and end month, but it doesn't work as expected.
How can I modify it to make it work as I want?
I want a screen like below
enter image description here
My screen is like this
enter image description here
$('.ui-datepicker-trigger').click(function () {
        var $td = $(this).closest('td');
        var $inputs = $td.find('input');
        var $startInput = $inputs.eq(0); // 첫 번째 input
        var $endInput = $inputs.eq(1); // 두 번째 input

        if ($inputs.length >= 2) {
            var startInputClass = $startInput.attr('class');

            if (startInputClass.includes('monthRangePicker')){
                // 월 선택기 설정
                $inputs.daterangepicker({
                    autoUpdateInput: false,
                    locale: {
                        format: 'YYYY-MM',
                        separator: ' ~ ',
                        applyLabel: '확인',
                        cancelLabel: '취소',
                        fromLabel: 'From',
                        toLabel: 'To',
                        customRangeLabel: '직접 설정',
                        weekLabel: 'W',
                        daysOfWeek: ['일', '월', '화', '수', '목', '금', '토'],
                        monthNames: ['1월', '2월', '3월', '4월', '5월', '6월', '7월', '8월', '9월', '10월', '11월', '12월']
                    },
                    drops: 'auto', // DateRangePicker의 드롭다운 방향을 자동으로 설정
                    
                    showDropdowns: true,
                }).on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
                    $startInput.val(picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM'));
                    $endInput.val(picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM'));

                    // 위치 조정 로직을 apply 이벤트에도 적용
                    var offset = $startInput.offset();
                    picker.container.css({
                        top: offset.top + $startInput.outerHeight(),
                        left: offset.left
                    });
                }).on('show.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
                    // 위치 조정 로직을 show 이벤트에도 적용
                    var offset = $startInput.offset();
                    picker.container.css({
                        top: offset.top + $startInput.outerHeight(),
                        left: offset.left
                    });

                    // 달력의 월 선택 버튼에 이벤트 추가
                    picker.container.find('.drp-calendar.left .month').off('click').on('click', function (e) {
                        var monthIndex = $(this).index();
                        var year = picker.leftCalendar.month.year();
                        var startDate = moment([year, monthIndex, 1]);
                        picker.setStartDate(startDate);
                        $startInput.val(startDate.format('YYYY-MM'));
                    });

                    picker.container.find('.drp-calendar.right .month').off('click').on('click', function (e) {
                        var monthIndex = $(this).index();
                        var year = picker.rightCalendar.month.year();
                        var endDate = moment([year, monthIndex]).endOf('month');
                        picker.setEndDate(endDate);
                        $endInput.val(endDate.format('YYYY-MM'));
                    });
                });

            } 
            $inputs.data('daterangepicker').toggle();
        }
    });


date range picker doesn't seem to have the functionality you are after

Try this out, should work:
$('.ui-datepicker-trigger').click(function () {
    var $td = $(this).closest('td');
    var $inputs = $td.find('input');
    var $startInput = $inputs.eq(0); // 첫 번째 input
    var $endInput = $inputs.eq(1); // 두 번째 input

    if ($inputs.length >= 2) {
        var startInputClass = $startInput.attr('class');

        if (startInputClass.includes('monthRangePicker')) {
            // 월 선택기 설정
            $inputs.daterangepicker({
                autoUpdateInput: false,
                locale: {
                    format: 'YYYY-MM',
                    separator: ' ~ ',
                    applyLabel: '확인',
                    cancelLabel: '취소',
                    fromLabel: 'From',
                    toLabel: 'To',
                    customRangeLabel: '직접 설정',
                    weekLabel: 'W',
                    daysOfWeek: ['일', '월', '화', '수', '목', '금', '토'],
                    monthNames: ['1월', '2월', '3월', '4월', '5월', '6월', '7월', '8월', '9월', '10월', '11월', '12월']
                },
                drops: 'auto', // DateRangePicker의 드롭다운 방향을 자동으로 설정
                showDropdowns: true,
                minDate: moment().startOf('year'),
                maxDate: moment().endOf('year')
            }).on('apply.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
                $startInput.val(picker.startDate.format('YYYY-MM'));
                $endInput.val(picker.endDate.format('YYYY-MM'));
            }).on('show.daterangepicker', function (ev, picker) {
                // Disable day selection and show only month selection
                picker.container.find('.calendar-table').find('td').each(function() {
                    var $cell = $(this);
                    var date = $cell.data('title');
                    if (date) {
                        var parts = date.split(' ');
                        var monthYear = parts[0] + '-' + parts[2];
                        $cell.html(monthYear).css({'pointer-events': 'none', 'background': 'none'});
                    }
                });
            });

            $inputs.data('daterangepicker').show();
        }
    }
});

